# React is undefined (Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert a working ReactJS application into TypeScript, and I've had some issues getting anything to work properly.

```
import React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Application from "./Application";

console.log(React); // undefined

ReactDOM.render(
    <Application/>, window.document.getElementById("application-wrapper")
);
```

The console throws an error at `<Application />`

When I import react like this, react loads:

```
import * as React from "react";
```

However, I want to use the import statement using the default export, because I import React using this import syntax in all the existing components:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class Whatever extends Component<Props, State> {
...
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` file contains this line allowing synthetic defaults:

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

My `webpack.config.js` file:

```
let path = require("path");
let config = {
    entry: "./src/main.tsx",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: "ts-loader",
            exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]       
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Not sure what I'm missing here....

Comment: console.log statement is not run when you actually run your application. Functions which are imported or exported only get run.

Comment: can you share your tsconfig.json? do you have "module": "es6"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module resolution is a little complicated because Typescript does it different than Babel and Webpack. If you want to know more you can check this comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5565#issuecomment-155216760

Going back to your problem, `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` tells Typescript to allow default imports from modules with no default export but the emitted code doesn't change. Because of that, you need to move the responsibility of resolving modules to Webpack or Babel.

To achieve that set <s>`moduleResolution`</s> `module` to <s>`ES6`</s>`es2015` in the Typescript config file.
The pipeline will look like this:

TS Code => (TypescriptCompiler) => JS Code with ES6 modules => (Webpack modules resolver) => JS Code

Comment: Thanks, buddy. To be honest, I played around with the tsconfig file until things started working, and completely forgot about this post. However, this answer is ultimately what solved the issue, so accepting this answer for the edification of future searches.

Comment: WebStorm is telling me that the only valid values for `moduleResolution` are `classic` and `node`. What's going on? Setting to ES6 has no effect.

Comment: @MattM. any luck? I have the exact situation.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed I think that I didn't use synthetic imports. I can't remember.

Comment: I just used import * as React from 'react' and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: the answer is indeed wrong, es6 is not a valid value for moduleResolution. for those who tried `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and it didnt work, adding `"esModuleInterop": true,` worked for me. these are similar but slightly different module transpilation modes for tsconfig.

Answer (score 8):

Set `"esModuleInterop": true` instead.

Answer (score 4):

In your typescript configuration i.e tsconfig.json `"esModuleInterop": true` and `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`. this will allow you to import CommonJS modules in compliance with es6 modules spec.